# I am getting sales email from wired email address in magento 2?

Tags: order-email, sales, transactional-mail, magento2.2.4

I have setup sales email address in the admin for sales_representative but still I am getting the sales email from another email address.

I have checked everywhere in admin and code but didn't get solution. Other emails like newsletter & customer registration are receiving from correct email.

So what is the problem and where I need to check this email issue for sales?

Comment: Can you confirm, you have setup "sales email sender" correctly in `Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales Email > Order` section?

Comment: I have setup in Store email address section then assign in Order section.

Comment: Also make sure you have updated respective store view or default settings, may be its overriding your settings.

Comment: I have checked in all store views. this is correct in all store views.